# dplyr mutate formula referencing previous rows

Tags: r, dplyr, formula, tidyr

I have a df of rainfall that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 270,900 x 3
   Sample.Date Gauge  Rainfall
   <date>      <fct>     <dbl>
 1 2016-02-01  563061        0
 2 2016-02-01  563064        0
 3 2016-02-01  563065        0
 4 2016-02-01  563069        0
 5 2016-02-01  563070        0
 6 2016-02-01  563083        0
 7 2016-02-01  563090        0
 8 2016-02-01  563146        0
 9 2016-02-01  563149        0
10 2016-02-01  566008        0
# ... with 270,890 more rows
```

I have about 134 rain gauges and daily rainfall data for each of them.

What I want to do is create a new column for each gauge to make a calculation, based on the previous day's calculation. Something along the lines of:

```
df %>%
group_by(Gauge) %>%
mutate(Rain_Calc = if_else(Sample.Date == "2016-01-02", "1.0", "") %>% #set Rain_Calc for Day 1
mutate(Rain_Calc = 0.7 * (Rainfall + Rain_Calc(Previous Day))
```

My df starts on 02/01/2016. I want the Rain_Calc value on that day (for all gauges) to equal 1.0.

Then, I want to calculate the "Rain Calc" values for the rest of the days which runs down the list (in sequential date order) and performs the calculation. I also need it grouped by Gauge.

How could I possibly achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of 10-15 rows and show expected output for it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new column for previous days rainfall in the same group and do your calculation on the two columns that are now in the same row.

```
df %>%
group_by(Gauge) %>%
arrange(Sample.Date) %>%
mutate(Rainfall.Lag1 = lag(Rainfall)) %>%
mutate(Sample.Date.Lag1 = lag(Sample.Date)) %>%
mutate(Rainfall.Lag1 = ifelse(as.double(difftime(Sample.Date, Sample.Date.Lag1, units="days")) == 1, Rainfall.Lag1, NA) %>%
mutate(Rain_Calc = 0.7 * (Rainfall + Rainfall.Lag1)
```

Comment: thanks. this seems to almost work - i get the error "could not find function Rain_Calc" on the last line

Comment: Oh I thought that was your own custom function. I don't understand what the calculation you are trying to do is? Can you please describe it perhaps just in mathematical terms?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understood your calculation, but i think accumulate is what you are looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
set.seed(1)
data <- tibble(date = rep(as.Date("2016-01-02")+0:2, 3), 
       gauge = rep(1:3,each=3), 
       rainfall = rgeom(9, 0.4))

data %>% group_by(gauge) %>% 
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(rain_calc = accumulate(rainfall[-1], ~0.7*(.x+.y),.init = 1))
```